# Bootstrap table export (excel) gives warning

Tags: excel, bootstrap-4

When I run the excel export for the bootstrap table (in the example) I get a warning when I try to open the file saying that the file format and the extension does not match and that is true. The file format is set to html and the extension is set to xls. Does anybody got a solution for this?

## Example

https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/export.html

## Warning

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pba1k.jpg)